# The specified JDK folder doesnot contain JDK (NetBean IDE Installer)

Tags: java, netbeans

This appears in netbeans IDE Installer,
what should I do here?

[image]

Comment: Well... enter the directory of a valid jdk...

Comment: You need to select `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10`  not the "lib" folder within that

Comment: Just install the JDK below and it will work with you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491365/the-specified-jdk-folder-doesnot-contain-jdk-netbean-ide-installer

Comment: Just install the JDK below and it will work with you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491365/the-specified-jdk-folder-doesnot-contain-jdk-netbean-ide-installer

Answer (score 2):

I had that issue when my JDK version was too far ahead of NetBeans. JDK 11 was a problem.

When I installed **JDK 8.x**, the NetBeans installation worked.

Also, note that the NetBeans installer requires the JRE in addition to the JDK, but doesn't mention this at first. (Again, I used JRE 8.x).

Answer (score -1):

This error means, that you put invaild JDK directory. Maybe it happens becouse you are addin "\lib" at the end - try without this.

You need to find place, where JDK is installed. Try to use "where javac" or this code below:

```
C:> for %i in (javac.exe) do @echo.   %~$PATH:i
```

Write this into cmd.exe, and then copy and paste this address in NetBeans (JDK for the Netbeans IDE).